# Fullpage.js with GSAP - Callback afterLoad animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, fullpage.js, gsap

I am trying to add some animations to fullpage.js with GSAP and have a question regarding the afterLoad function. Here's my code (with codepen link included)

```
$("#wrapper").fullpage({
  verticalCentered:true,
  scrollingSpeed: 1000,

  sectionSelector: "section",

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    var loadedSection = $(this);

    if (index == 2) {
      TweenMax.from(".second h1", 1, {opacity:0, left:"-20px"});
    }
  }
});
```

What I would like to do is, use the afterLoad function to animate (fadeIn / slideIn) elements of the current section. My codepen link is [here](http://codepen.io/vividuaelsaphe/pen/wWBORm).

I am able to do this successfully (pls see the second section of the pen, you'll see it fades in), but the problem is it doesn't start with the animation. It has a delay before the animation starts, so during that delay, the elements need to be hidden (Not sure how to do this, I tried visibility:hidden to start with, it didn't work).

I am able to achieve the same thing with onLeave (but from 2nd section onwards).

Looking forward! Cheers!

**UPDATE**

I managed to figure it out. Thanks for Alvaro for chipping in a prompt reply. Here's the updated code:

```
$("#wrapper").fullpage({
  verticalCentered:true,
  scrollingSpeed: 1000,

  sectionSelector: "section",

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    var loadedSection = $(this);

    if (index == 1) {
      $(".second h1").hide();
    }

    if (index == 2) {
      $(".second h1").show();
      TweenMax.from(".second h1", 1, {opacity:0, left:"-20px", delay:0.5});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is not the delay but the fact that the element is visible in the first instance.

Comment: Hi alvaro, thanks for the reply. Funny, I just found it before reading this. But thank you very much for the hint. Works like a charm. I am updating the codepen. Thanks! I have updated it on the post.